# How can I control interger_number EditText stop number decrease once 0 reached?

Tags: android, kotlin, integer, negative-number

My activity has increase btn, decrease btn, productpoint and integer_number for count.
when I clciked decrease btn, integer_number and productpoint changed negative.
So, I dont want get negative.

[image]

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details)

        var productpoint = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.productPoint)
        var point=0
        val inc_val=16000


        increase.setOnClickListener {
            increaseInteger()
            point+=inc_val
            productpoint.text = point.toString()+"P"}


        decrease.setOnClickListener {
            decreaseInteger()
            point-=inc_val
            productpoint.text = point.toString()+"P"
        }

 fun increaseInteger() {
        display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() + 1)
    }

    fun decreaseInteger() {
        display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
    }

    private fun display(number: Int) {
        integer_number.setText("$number")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume initial value of `integer_number` TextView is larger than 0, here is my solution.

```
fun increaseInteger() {
    val newValue = integer_number.text.toString().toInt() + 1
    if (newValue > 0 && !decrease.isEnabled) {
        decrease.isEnabled = true
    }
    display(newValue)
}

fun decreaseInteger() {
    val newValue = integer_number.text.toString().toInt() - 1
    if (newValue <= 0) {
        decrease.isEnabled = false
    }
    display(newValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
fun decreaseInteger() {
        if(integer_number.text.toString().toInt()<=0)
{
        display(0)
}
display(integer_number.text.toString().toInt() - 1)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for u r comment. but display can be "-1" also decrease button can click continue. this situation make productpoint will be minus degree continue. so i want make that if display "0" -> decrease button can not click else if display >0-> decrease button can click.